# Flutter expand/collapse container without overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anybody have a clue how to achieve expand/collapse animation for a given `Container` widget?

I tried to use `ExpandablePanel` but it is not what I really want, because I want to render a `Column` within a `Container`, and if the `Container` is collapsed I want to show only 150px from it, otherwise it should have the height of the content.

Clicking on the arrow the `Container` should toggle it's state.

Below are some images which represents the goal:

[Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ztjM.png)

[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RycJl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The overflow error is thrown because when the column is collapsed there is no room to contain all the children inside the column.

What do we do when we have a column with children's height larger than the screen height? We use scrolling!

So you can wrap your column with `SingleChildScrollView` widget to make the column scrollable, so when it collapses it doesn't complain about the children's height, instead, the scrolling functionality handles them because you can scroll in a column even if it has very small width.